# Is there a native way to address a non-rectangle object on canvas in js?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've created a grid of several distorted rectangles made with Bezier curves. Each rectangle has its own color on the picture.

Let's say, I want to add hover effect for each of these rectangles, therefore I need to know its dimensions. Since I can fill or stroke the figure I assume that there is some way to get them, but I'm not sure.

Here is the example of the rectangles:

[image]

So the question is, is there some method in the canvas API with which I can achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use [isPointInPath(Path2D, x, y)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) method.

Note that if you don't use the Path2D object, you can also call it just with `isPointInPath(x, y)`, but then it will check on the currently being drawn path (declared with `beginPath()`).

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var myPath = new Path2D();
myPath.bezierCurveTo(50, 100, 180, 10, 20, 10);
myPath.lineTo(50, 100);

function draw(hover) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = hover ? 'red' : 'green';
  ctx.fill(myPath);
}

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
    y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
  var hover = ctx.isPointInPath(myPath, x, y)
  draw(hover)
};
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome. Although I wonder about the support :)

Comment: @Dronich Well for support, if I do remember correctly, all browsers supporting html5 canvas did support this method. However, the Path2D Constructor as less support. But as I said, there are polyfills easily findable, andyou can even just redraw the path before testing against its position. A better implementation would be a rough squared check against every shape's bounding box first, then a more precise isPointInPath against possible pathes.